# Partial diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I'm currently writing my dissertation and I'm stuck.
I need to solve the non linear matrix equation

$$ \mathbf{FC}=\mathbf{C}\boldsymbol{\varepsilon} $$

where the matrix $ \mathbf{F} $ depends the elements of the matrix $\mathbf{C}$;
the diagonalization procedure is iterative. 
The matrix $\mathbf{C^{-1}FC}$ is symmetric and is partitioned as follow:
[image]
Once the matrix $ \mathbf{F} $ is diagonalized, the total energy can be calculated as the sum of the occupied orbital diagonal elements of the matrix $ \boldsymbol{\varepsilon} $ plus other various terms:

$$ \mathcal{E}={\displaystyle \sum_{\mathrm{occ}}}\varepsilon+\mathrm{other\, terms}
  $$
Here's the point: I don't understand why, given the fact that the energy is invariant with respect to unitary transformations among occupied orbitals and among virtual orbitals, the full iterative diagonalization can be replaced by a pseudodigonalization procedure which consists in the annihilation of virtual-occupied blocks of the matrix $\mathbf{C^{-1}FC}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your schematic isn't very clear; obviously $C^{-1} F C$ is square, but it doesn't look like it in the schematic, and it's not clear what fills the rest of the blocks except for the symmetry requirement. Also, your actual question is posed in very physical language. It would be helpful for MSE folks if you could rephrase in more mathematical language. In particular, it sounds like you are saying that the energy is invariant with respect to certain "block unitary" transformations, but some clarification there would be good.